# Vscode extension code inside npm workspaces monorepo vsce package error

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, visual-studio-extensions, workspace, monorepo

Im writing a vs code extension inside npm workspaces monorepo,
when I try to package it using `vsce package`, I get this error:

```
This extension consists of <files_count> files, out of which <files_count> are JavaScript files. For performance reasons, you should bundle your extension: https://aka.ms/vscode-bundle-extension . You should also exclude unnecessary files by adding them to your .vscodeignore: https://aka.ms/vscode-vscodeignore
```

I'm already using the .vscodeignore file, it seems that the `vsce package` command trying to get files outside the project folder inside the monorepo

my goal is to get the .vsix file that include only the extension code

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I found I had to ignore each parent level. Run `vsce ls` to make sure the files left are the ones you'd like to publish:

```
# /workspaces/vscode-theme/.vscodeignore

../../**
../**
```